# .htaccess modRewrite - find out the underlying url that is trying to be resolved?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, hosting

I am having trouble with an htaccess file that works on my local testing setup but not when uploaded to my production server, even though I have other sites on that server which have working .htaccess setups.

Is there any way (perhaps with a custom 404 page) that I can find out the url that .htaccess has re-written to, so that I can debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

what is your trouble?

get you an internal server error or didn't execute any of your rules?

a shoot in the dark ... if your rules doesn't match it could be that you have something like this in your .htaccess

```
RewriteRule /home/ /index.php?s=1&l=1 [L]
```

... then try the change in

```
RewriteRule home /index.php?s=1&l=1 [L]
```

without the leading slash "/"

Comment: no it's not that, I'm getting 404 errors, where the testing site is working fine. I want to find out exactly what underlying URL htaccess is trying to get to, if any, to try and debug the file

Comment: Hi Donald. Thanks but I've fixed the problem now anyway (see my other question if you're curious!) It would still be nice to be able to somehow echo the actual url .htaccess is trying to retrieve in case of any future problems :)